# How to have custom error code check for axios response interceptor?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using graphql in my application and it sends the following response in error.

As you may have noticed graphql send all the errors as status code 200. And the error I have returned from the API is under `data.errors`.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Error: Token has expired",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 7
          }
        ],
        "path": [
          "createGame"
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "403",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "Error: Error: Token has expired"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "data": {
      "createGame": null
    }
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  "config": {
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/graphql",
    "method": "post",
    "data": "{\"query\":\"\\n    mutation {\\n      createGame (name: \\\"SA\\\", shortName: \\\"s\\\") {\\n        id,\\n        name,\\n        shortName\\n      }\\n    }\\n  \"}",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoxLCJlbXBsb3llZUlkIjowLCJ1c2VyUm9sZUlkIjozLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYiQxMCRwNTE2V1hnSGZXdWx6czVmY2o2ZGp1Q09lUzF0UUw3U2MySEIuMDRPUmpWekh6VnduSTNwNiIsImlzQWN0aXZlIjp0cnVlLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDE5LTA4LTE5VDA5OjMxOjA5LjAzOVoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDE5LTA4LTE5VDA5OjMxOjA5LjA0MVoifSwiaWF0IjoxNTY3ODcyNTk2LCJleHAiOjE1Njc4NzI2MDZ9.HpNE9m5YEUv0qgBHxsEoQMd1p29TkOqvQzYF7ptljJ0"
    },
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:4200/graphql",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

The problem I am having is that I am integrating axios response intercetor in my Front-end

```js
http.interceptors.response.use(
    /**
     * Leave response as it is.
     */
    (response: any) =>  response,
    /**
     * This interceptor checks if the response had a 401 status code, which means
     * that the access token used for the request has expired. It then refreshes
     * the access token and resends the original request.
     */
    unauthorizedResponseHandlerInterceptor
  );
```

And the `unauthorizedResponseHandlerInterceptor` function is only called by Axios when then there is an error but my graphql server is returning the status as 200 so the function does not get called.

Is there any way for me to modify the axios response interceptor so that it checks the value in **data.errors** instead of **status**

Answer (score 5):

The first callback of the interceptor gets called when there is no error. You could do some custom check based on how your API sends errors:

```js
http.interceptors.response.use(
    /**
     * Leave response as it is.
     */
    (response: any) => {
      if (response.data.errors) {
          let customError = new Error(response.data.errors[0].message);
          response.original_status = response.status
          response.status = response.data.errors[0].extensions.code
          customError.response = response;
          return Promise.reject(customError);
      }
      return response;
    },
    /**
     * This interceptor checks if the response had a 401 status code, which means
     * that the access token used for the request has expired. It then refreshes
     * the access token and resends the original request.
     */
    unauthorizedResponseHandlerInterceptor
  );
```

It is quite flexible. As shown above, you can even turn a successful call into an error, by returning `Promise.reject()` in the interceptor.

Here's a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/pvb1kj87/

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  if (response.data.errors) {
    let customError = new Error(response.data.errors[0].message);
    response.original_status = response.status
    response.status = response.data.errors[0].extensions.code
    // add some properties to make it look like a regular axios error
    customError.response = response;
    customError.request = response.request;
    customError.config = response.config;
    customError.isAxiosError = true; // or not

    return Promise.reject(customError);
  }
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

(async () => {

  console.log('*** regular axios error:')

  await axios.get(`https://example.com/DOESNOTEXIST`)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('success -->', data)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('error -->', e)
    })

  console.log('*\n*\n*')
  console.log('*** simulating error:')

  axios.get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/d7hbp`)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('success -->', data)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('error -->', e)
    })

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
Open dev tools and check the console!
```

Comment: But won't i need to return something from this function? If i return something it will return to the component and i will have to handle all the token information there too.

Comment: If i have to handle all the token errors in the component itself, it will defeat the purpose of the interceptor.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get what you mean, but I added a fiddle/snippet to showcase how the interceptor would work. I feel it does can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you mean that return Promise.reject(customError); transfers the flow inside the err function? But when i check it the flow does not reach there

Comment: It doesnt transfer the flow to the error interceptor, no (so if you wanted `unauthorizedResponseHandlerInterceptor` to be called there, you'd have to call it yourself, but I'd argue that doesn't seem so bad), but returning the rejected promise does redirect the floe to the axios `catch` callbacks. You can observe that in the demo above, the `console.log('error -->', e)` gets called both times (with the "natural" error and with the "injected" error).