# Is it necessary to check if axios response status is 200 or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

Is it necessary to check if `axios.get()` response status is 200 ?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api');
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setState(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  fetch();
}, []);
```

or I can do this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetch = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api');
      setState(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  fetch();
}, []);
```

if it is, what is best practice?

Comment: You should definitely check if `data` is valid. Most of the time, that's when the response status is `200`.

Comment: or may be checking **OK** status `statusText: 'OK',` .... as sometimes it might be 201 etc.,

Comment: It depends on server configuration. Some servers are configured to return all responses, including rejections/errors with a status of 200 (which is wrong, by common practice). In most cases, `status` is an indicator that everything went as expected (or not) on server side and therefore the returned `data` has the expected format.

Comment: By default, `axios` throws an error for non 2xx responses. If you were using `fetch` then you should definitely check for the response's status as `fetch` doesn't throw unless it's a network error.

Comment: @ivanatias the `fetch()` response has a handy [ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't need to check. But technically, it totally depends on how your team interpret HTTP protocol.

Even though it’s discouraged, I’ve seen teams that totally disregard the standard semantics of HTTP status code, blindly set status code to 200 in almost all cases, then encode the success/failure state within data payload, e.g. `data.success == true or false`. In that case checking status code means nothing.

Axios is just a library that facilitates message exchanging over HTTP. The real working horse is HTTP protocol. You can even customize axios to determine what case is deemed "error", like shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839551/how-to-have-custom-error-code-check-for-axios-response-interceptor). Better consult your backend colleagues to understand their server response convention and reach consensus within your team.